# How to use Grails findAll with toString from a complex object?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there any way to use Grails findAll to a toString from a Complex Object?

I have an Object named Person (example).

Person has firstName and lastName attributes and there is a toString method that returns "FirstName: " + firstName + "LastName: " + lastName

And there is another object that have Person named Group.
Group has an attribute of Person.

I want to search like:

```
Group.findAll{
    ilike("person.toString", "%FirstName%")
}
```

I'm getting the following:

```
could not resolve property: person.toString of: com.test.Group. Stacktrace follows:
Message: could not resolve property: person.toString of: com.test.Group
    Line | Method
->>  670 | doCall               in grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria$_list_closure2
```

Is there a way to use findAll comparing to a toString method? I can't create a getFirstAndLastName because the object is a plugin to another project and can't be modified.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use findAll comparing to a toString method?

No.  The only way to invoke `toString`, or any other method, on entities would be to retrieve them, bring them into the app so the instances can be created and then invoke the methods.  If the `toString` happens to return something that you can simulate without actually invoking the method then you might have options but the answer to the question as asked is "no".

I hope that helps.